# Multiple Selections with Radio Buttons

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I need to permit more than one selection, for example one user can choose the three options or only two or one: This only permit one, correct?:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk" class="semLargura" /> Milk <br />
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" class="semLargura" /> Butter <br />
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese" class="semLargura" /> Cheese <br />
```

This permits 3 options

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk" class="semLargura" /> Milk <br />
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Butter" class="semLargura" /> Butter <br />
<input type="radio" name="group3" value="Cheese" class="semLargura" /> Cheese <br />
```

But in this case, how i can delete a select? For example i choose Milk, Butter and Cheese, but i want to remove the Butter after selected. Something like reset button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use checkboxes instead of radiobuttons? They work exactly the way you want...