# HTML radio buttons with multiple selections at once

Tags: html

Is it possible to have multiple selections with radio buttons at once?
Or shall I use only the checkbox selection?

[image]

Unfortunately the questions, which I found below:

[Multiple Selections with Radio Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165388/multiple-selections-with-radio-buttons)

[HTML radio buttons allowing multiple selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982993/html-radio-buttons-allowing-multiple-selections)

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

https://university.webflow.com/article/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-select-inputs

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_radio

clearly shows, that there is no option such this!?!

Maybe these examples are too simple and don't show more advanced possibilities?

Could you advise?

Comment: Being able to select multiple radio buttons within in the same group would defeat the purpose of using radio buttons. Use checkboxes.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. SO unfortunately there is no option then...

Comment: yes, with radio buttons there is no option as I know, but if it's about design then you can design checkbox as radio buttons, but  I think that's not the requirement.

Comment: Radio buttons allow a selection of one of many (exactly one). Checkboxes allow a selection of any of many (0 or more). You *could* style checkboxes to look like radio buttons, though I would advice against that unless you want to confuse users. You can also create multiple groups of radio buttons, where each group allows a single value.

Comment: You can try the code I posted below and if it works please let us know.

Comment: Unfortunately is not valid. It returns the same as without. Maybe some another one exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you have to, but it is recommended to use checkbox if you want to allow multiple selection.

```
    <div>
    <form target="_blank" onsubmit="try {return window.confirm(&quot;You are submitting information to an external page.\nAre you sure?&quot;);} catch (e) {return false;}">
    <input type="radio"> first<br>
    <input type="radio"> second<br>
    <input type="radio"> third<br>
    </form>
    </div>
```